# Why do themes have `while( have_posts() )` in templates like single.php?

Tags: loop

Example: https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/single.php

Isn't single.php's purpose to show single posts?

Comment: Since your question is "why?", I don't have an answer. It works fine without the "while"; same with page.php. I notice twentyten leaves it out.

Comment: Good catch @Doug!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to ensure that all the content is displayed properly. Some functions are not available outside of The Loop, as it's called, so depending on what you are doing, it may be advantageous to start the loop, even if you're relatively certain it will only be used for one post object.

Comment: `have_posts()` just returns true or false, `the_post()` is what sets up the data.

Comment: I'm aware of that, what I was trying to say, and I suppose I did a poor job of it, was that it can potentially catch errors and help for things to run more smoothly given atypical conditions.

Comment: +1 Milo, though `have_posts()` will 'close' the loop (`loop_end`) on the final iteration.